# Create custom Kibana dashboard with custom query

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have 2 log files, 1 for Apache and another for a custom app. To query the logs  for errors, the Apache log has log level tag as ERROR while the custom app has a response code tag 500.

I have a dashboard that shows the total errors in Apache log that matches tag = Error and second for total errors that match response code = 500.

My challenge is how to combine both errors as one rather than separating it. I have searched online for documentation on how to define query as global error = total with tag = error in apache log TYPE & total with response = 500 in xxx log type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to somehow correlate Apache and application logs but simply want all events that match either condition, i.e. the sum of both types of errors, this works (adjust field names to taste):

```
(type:apache AND tags:error) OR (type:custom AND response_code:500)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. What panel type should I select to make use of this query?

Comment: I don't know, what type of result are you looking for? Queries are panel-independent.

Comment: Just to give an idea of what i am trying to do. I created [blank json](http://snag.gy/0RsIv.jpg) file from the black template. I want to add that Global Total Error barchart in a new row. Click on [Add panel](http://snag.gy/5YIpt.jpg) to empty row. I was assuming i should be able to add the query here.

Comment: No, queries are added at the top and then panels can be connected to one or more such queries. It sounds like you're looking for a histogram panel.

Comment: Ah I see, the query bit has more on what type of query to make (lucene, regex & topN). Let me read up on the 3 query types and see which works

Comment: Hi thanks, this worked. The only thing or issue I have is without indicating the date filter, the query won't run. I have read where you can use this code '"lt": "now-30d"' to query for last 30days logs but can't get it to work with the query code.

Comment: Have you added a time filter at the top? Since it's Logstash data you're dealing with you may be better off starting from a Logstash dashboard rather than a blank one.